# How can I turn a list of properties into a stringlist?

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, delphi-xe2, tstringlist

I have a component with a lot of properties, many of which are types.

For example:

```
BackgroundStyle = [bsSolid, bsGradient, bsNone]

BorderStyle = [bsNone, bsSingle, bsWide]
```

I am building a form to allow the user to configure these properties at runtime and I would like to populate some dropdown lists dynamically, rather than having to type all of them in by hand.

Is this possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use RTTI for that.  Specifically, look at the `GetPropInfo()` and `GetEnumName()` functions in the `TypInfo` unit.

Answer (score 0):

Remy is on the ball with this one. Lately I just happen to do something similar and a bit of refactoring (within a text editor, so you mileage may vary with the complier):

```
class function TEnumerationRoutines.TitleCaseDescriptionFromOptions<T>: TStrings;
var
  LRttiContext : TRttiContext;
  LRttiEnumerationType: TRttiEnumerationType;
  LTypeInfo : Pointer;
  LPTypeInfo : PTypeInfo;
  lp: Integer;
begin
  LTypeInfo := TypeInfo(T);

  LPTypeInfo := PTypeInfo(LTypeInfo);
  if LPTypeInfo^.Kind <> tkEnumeration then
    raise Exception.Create('Type is not an enum');

  Result := TStringList.Create;

  LRttiEnumerationType := LRttiContext.GetType(LTypeInfo) as TRttiEnumerationType;

  for lp := LRttiEnumerationType.MinValue to LRttiEnumerationType.MaxValue do
    Result.Add(GetEnumName(LTypeInfo, Ord(lp)));
end;
```

and call it with:

```
MyStrings := TEnumerationRoutines.TitleCaseDescriptionFromOptions<BackgroundStyle>;
```

or

```
MyStrings := TEnumerationRoutines.TitleCaseDescriptionFromOptions<BorderStyle>;
```